# C# resize generated image; bitmap, argument exception

Tags: c#, bitmap, zooming, picturebox, argumentexception

[image]

I have an Image object that I'm trying to resize from a picture box via Bitmap.

I have a source to the picture box on my desktop and the code is as follows

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
Size newSize = new Size(100,100);

image = new Bitmap( (Image)image, newSize); 
// here I get Parameter not valid, Argument Exception was unhandled

pictureBox1.Image = (Image)image;
```

Why is that exception being thrown?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  The code you supply is working as expected, there are now exceptions raised in .NET 4.0.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.5; I don't think that is the issue but what are some things that could lead to the exception? Mine does not have the same good fortune of working like your's does. Do you know if there are constraints with the location of the pictureBox1 image or who can use it a t the same time?

Comment: I am only able to get a `NullReferenceException` when the picturebox does not have an image loaded.  I am testing in winforms, in a form load event. The http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wh0045z.aspx documentation for this constructor raises only `Exception`.

Comment: Can you show us the exception message and exactly where is thrown.

Comment: I saw I miss entered the size of newSize, they should be in the order of 100,000 instead of 100; does the size make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't understand why you create 2 bitmap objects? 
Why do not something like this:

```
Bitmap image = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
Size newSize = new Size(100,100);
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap((Image)image, newSize);
image.Dispose();
```

However I don't think that exception is caused by shown code. 
It's possible to read above on screen :

> newSize {Width = 128000 Height = 59500}

Have you calculated how big is that picture?

Size x 4 bytes of format = 3.0464^ 10.

I don't think that you have enough memory to allocate this image.